# Por qué no puedo crear un objeto desde otra clase?

Tags: java, objeto

Estoy creando un objeto utilizando el metodo agregarSucursal desde Banco que llama al constructor de la clase en cuestion (Sucursal) para crear un nuevo objeto de esta clase.

El problema que estoy teniendo es que aparentemente el objeto Sucursal no se está creando, ya que el printOut que está dentro del constructor arroja

"Sucursal *vacio* creada" y a su vez si llamo al metodo imprimirSucursales, no muestra ningun objeto.

EDITO: Agrego todas las clases. Incorporé las sugerencias y el problema sigue persistiendo. Desde Main llamo a los métodos en la clase Banco desde donde se crean los objetos sucursales y cliente.

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

import java.util.Scanner;

//Main

```
public class Main {

    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Bank banco = new Bank("Banco Central");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        printOptions();

        boolean quit = false;
        while (!quit) {
            System.out.println("6. Imprimir lista de opciones");
            int option = scanner.nextInt();
            switch (option) {
                case 0:
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    addBranch();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printBranches();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    printOptions();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printOptions() {
        System.out.println("Enter option");
        System.out.println("0. Quit");
        System.out.println("1. Agregar sucursal");
        System.out.println("2. Imprimir sucursales");
        System.out.println("3. Agregar cliente nuevo a sucursal con transaccion inicial");
        System.out.println("4. Agregar transaccion a cliente existente");
        System.out.println("5. Imprimir lista de clientes de sucursal"); //agregar opcional de mostrar transacciones

    }

    public static void addBranch() {
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de la sucursal");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.nextLine();

        banco.addBranch(name);
    }

    public static void printBranches() {
        banco.printBranches();

    }


}
```

//Banco

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Bank {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Branch> branches = new ArrayList<Branch>();

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public Bank(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.branches = new ArrayList<Branch>();
    }

    public void addBranch(String branchName) {
        Branch newBranch = new Branch(branchName);
        branches.add(newBranch);
        //System.out.println(nuevaSucursal.getName() + "creada");

    }


    //2

    public void printBranches() {
        System.out.println("Lista de sucursales");
        for (int i = 0; i < this.branches.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(this.branches.get(i).getName());

        }


    }


    //4
    public void addTransaction(Client client, double transaccion) {
        Branch.addTransaction(client, transaccion); //al ser STATIC no hace falta crear un Objeto Sucursal para poder llamarlo

    }


    //GETTERS & SETTERS

    public ArrayList<Branch> getBranches() { //devolver sout mejor?
        return branches;
    }

    public void addSucursal(String sucursal) {
        this.branches.add(new Branch(sucursal));
    }
}
```

//Sucursal

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Branch {

    private String branchName;
    ArrayList<Client> clients;

    public Branch(String name) {
        this.branchName = name;
        this.clients = new ArrayList<Client>();
        System.out.println("Sucursal " + name + " creada.");
    }

    public void agregarCliente(String name, double initialTransaction) {
        clients.add(new Client(name, initialTransaction));
        System.out.println("Cliente " + name + " agregado a esta sucursal. Transaccion inicial: " + initialTransaction);
    }

    public static void addTransaction(Client client, double transaccion) {
        client.addTransactions(transaccion); //al ser STATIC no hace falta crear un Objeto Sucursal para poder llamarlo

    }

    public static Branch agregarSucursal(String nombre) {
        return new Branch(nombre);
    }

//GETTERS SETTERS

    public String getName() {
        return this.branchName;
    }
}
```

//Cliente

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Client {

    private String clientName;
    ArrayList<Double> transactions = new ArrayList<Double>();

    public Client(String clientName, double initialTransactions) {
        this.clientName = clientName;
        this.transactions.add(initialTransactions);
        System.out.println("Cliente creado");
    }

    public String getClientName() {
        return clientName;
    }

    public void setClientName(String clientName) {
        this.clientName = clientName;
    }

    public ArrayList<Double> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }

    public void addTransactions(double transaction) {
        this.transactions.add(transaction);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tenías errores como mencionó  Lucio Lo Verde. Ahí te dejo un ejemplo, fijate que le agregué algunos métodos, para que veas el funcionamiento

Comment: Te escribo por acá para mencionarte que olvidé decirte sobre los modificadores de acceso que le pones a los ArrayList de tus clases, en tu código los declaras como publicos, cuando los debes tener como privados ó bien protegidos, debes tener cuidado con eso ya que esas listas solo se deberían manipular a través de los métodos que vos creaste en sus respectivas clases (que para eso están) de otra forma si los dejas como públicos el cliente podría manipular las listas sin usar los métodos que implementaste

Comment: Gracias, lo voy a tener en cuenta. Como recién estoy empezando a programar generalmente empiezo declarando casi todo publico y después voy ocultando las cosas en la medida que me doy cuenta.

Comment: Edité nuevamente agregando unas mejoras

Answer (score 3):

Tenes un error con la variable "sucursal" en el método "agregarSucursal", en tu código crea una nueva sucursal y queda sin guardar en el ArrayList de Sucursales, cuando sale del método "agregarSucursal" la sucursal que creaste deja de existir.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Bank {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Sucursal> sucursales;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public Bank(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        sucursales = new ArrayList<Sucursal>;
    }

    public void agregarSucursal(String sucursalName){
        Sucursal suc = new Sucursal(sucursalName);
        sucursales.add(suc);

    }


    public void imprimirSucursales(){
        System.out.println("Lista de sucursales");
        for(int i = 0; i<this.sucursales.size();i++){
            System.out.println(this.sucursales.get(i).getName());

        }


    }
```

Clase Sucursal:
En esta clase inicializaste dos veces el ArrayList de Clientes, eso solo se debería inicializar en el constructor.

```
public class Sucursal {

    private String sucursalName;
    private ArrayList<Cliente> clientes;

    public Sucursal(String name) {
        this.sucursalName = name;
        this.clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
        System.out.println("Sucursal " + name + " creada.");
    }

    public void agregarCliente(String name, double initialTransaction){
        clientes.add(new Cliente(name, initialTransaction));
        System.out.println("Cliente " + name + " agregado a esta sucursal. Transaccion inicial: " + initialTransaction);
    }

    public static void agregarTransaccion(Cliente cliente, double transaccion){
        cliente.addTransactions(transaccion); 

    }

//GETTERS SETTERS


    public String getName() {
        return sucursalName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Agregué la clase cliente para que tengas un panorama más completo, ya que realicé las correciones y sigo teniendo el problema. Si necesitas que postee el Main dime. Y gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    //creamos un Scanner para cada tipo de dato
    public static Scanner scannerInt;
    public static Scanner scannerDouble;
    public static Scanner scannerString;
    public static Bank banco;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scannerInt =new Scanner(System.in);
        scannerDouble =new Scanner(System.in);
        scannerString =new Scanner(System.in);
        banco =new Bank("Banco Central");

        boolean quit = false;
        while (!quit) {
            printOptions();
            int option = getScannerInt().nextInt();
            int subOption =0;
            String strEntrada;
            double dEntrada;
            switch (option) {
                case 0:
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    addBranch();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printBranches();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Elija Nº de Sucursal:");
                    printBranches();
                    option =getScannerInt().nextInt();
                    //controlamos si el número ingresado por el usuario corresponde a una sucursal, ya que de lo contrario
                    //se produciría un error. Fijate que no saldrá del bucle mientras la sucursal no exista.
                    //nota: habría que hacerlo también con clientes, pero es mas que nada un ejemplo para que veas cómo se controla.
                    if(existeSucursal(option)) System.out.println("Escogió Sucursal: "+obternerBranchPorNumSucurs(option).getName());
                    else
                    {
                        do{
                            System.out.println("El número de Sucursal ingresado no existe.");
                            System.out.println("Ingrese número de Sucursal nuevamente:");
                            option =getScannerInt().nextInt();
                        }while(!existeSucursal(option));
                        System.out.println("Escogió Sucursal: "+obternerBranchPorNumSucurs(option).getName());
                    }
                    System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del Cliente:");
                    strEntrada =getScannerString().nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Ingrese transaccion inicial:");
                    dEntrada =getScannerDouble().nextDouble();
                    obternerBranchPorNumSucurs(option).agregarCliente(strEntrada, dEntrada);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Elija Nº de Sucursal correspondiente al Cliente:");
                    printBranches();
                    option =getScannerInt().nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Escogió Sucursal: "+obternerBranchPorNumSucurs(option).getName());
                    obternerBranchPorNumSucurs(option).printClient();
                    System.out.println("Elija Nº de Cliente al cual desea agregar transaccion");
                    subOption =getScannerInt().nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Escogió cliente: "+obtenerClientePorNumClienYnumSucurs(subOption, option).getClientName());
                    System.out.println("Ingrese transaccion:");
                    dEntrada =getScannerDouble().nextDouble();
                    obternerBranchPorNumSucurs(option).addTransaction(obtenerClientePorNumClienYnumSucurs(subOption, option), dEntrada);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Elija Nº de Sucursal:");
                    printBranches();
                    option =getScannerInt().nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Escogió Sucursal: "+obternerBranchPorNumSucurs(option).getName());
                    obternerBranchPorNumSucurs(option).printClient();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println("Elija Nº de Sucursal correspondiente al Cliente:");
                    printBranches();
                    option =getScannerInt().nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Escogió Sucursal: "+obternerBranchPorNumSucurs(option).getName());
                    obternerBranchPorNumSucurs(option).printClient();
                    System.out.println("Elija Nº de Cliente al cual desea agregar transaccion");
                    subOption =getScannerInt().nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Escogió cliente: "+obtenerClientePorNumClienYnumSucurs(subOption, option).getClientName());
                    obtenerClientePorNumClienYnumSucurs(subOption, option).printTransactions();
            }
        }
    }
    public static Scanner getScannerInt() {
        return scannerInt;
    }
    public static Scanner getScannerDouble() {
        return scannerDouble;
    }
    public static Scanner getScannerString() {
        return scannerString;
    }
    public static Bank getBanco() {
        return banco;
    }    
    public static void printOptions() {
        System.out.println("Enter option");
        System.out.println("0. Quit");
        System.out.println("1. Agregar sucursal");
        System.out.println("2. Imprimir sucursales");
        System.out.println("3. Agregar cliente nuevo a sucursal con transaccion inicial");
        System.out.println("4. Agregar transaccion a cliente existente");
        System.out.println("5. Imprimir lista de clientes de sucursal");
        System.out.println("6. Imprimir lista de transacciones de Cliente");
    }
    public static void addBranch() {
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de la sucursal:");
        String entrada =getScannerString().nextLine();
        getBanco().addBranch(entrada);
    }
    public static void printBranches() {
        getBanco().printBranches();
    }
    public static List<Branch> obtenerBranches(){
        return getBanco().getBranches();
    }
    public static Branch obternerBranchPorNumSucurs(int numSucurs){
        return getBanco().getBranches().get(numSucurs -1);
    }
    //verifica si existe la sucursal
    private static boolean existeSucursal(int numSucursal){
        return (numSucursal -1 >=0 && numSucursal -1 <obtenerBranches().size());
    }
    public static List<Client> obtenerClientesDeSucursal(int numSucursal){
        return obtenerBranches().get(numSucursal -1).getClients();
    }
    public static Client obtenerClientePorNumClienYnumSucurs(int numClien, int numSucurs){
        return obtenerClientesDeSucursal(numSucurs).get(numClien -1);
    }
}

class Bank {

    private String name;
    private List<Branch> branches;//recordá que se inicializa dentro de un constructor

    public Bank(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        branches = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public void addBranch(String branchName) {
        branches.add(new Branch(branchName));
    }
    //2
    public void printBranches() {
        System.out.println("Lista de sucursales:");
        int longitud =branches.size();//recordá hacer esto para mayor eficiencia, así no calcula la longitud en cada iteración
        for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {
            System.out.println("Nº "+(i+1)+": "+branches.get(i).getName());
        }
    }
    //4
//    public  void addTransaction(Client client, double transaccion) {
//        Branch.addTransaction(client, transaccion); //al ser STATIC no hace falta crear un Objeto Sucursal para poder llamarlo
//        //No hace falta crear objeto Branch por que lo tenes guardado en lista 'branches'
//    }
    //devolver sout mejor? Respuesta: no, así está bien, devolves lista, así cuando necesites acceder a una Branch lo haces
    //con el método 'get(index)'
    public List<Branch> getBranches() {
        return branches;
    }
}
class Branch {

    private String branchName;
    private List<Client> clients;

    public Branch(String name) {
        branchName = name;//acá no hace falta el 'this' por que no hay confusión
        clients = new ArrayList<>();//idem
        System.out.println("Sucursal " + name + " creada.");
    }
    public void agregarCliente(String name, double initialTransaction) {
        clients.add(new Client(name, initialTransaction));
        System.out.println("Cliente " + name + " agregado a sucursal "+branchName+". Transaccion inicial: " + initialTransaction);
    }
    public static void addTransaction(Client client, double transaccion) {
        client.addTransactions(transaccion); //al ser STATIC no hace falta crear un Objeto Sucursal para poder llamarlo
    }
    public static Branch agregarSucursal(String nombre) {
        return new Branch(nombre);
    }
    public String getName() {
        return branchName;
    }
    public List<Client> getClients() {
        return clients;
    }
    public void printClient(){
        System.out.println("Lista de Clientes:");
        int longitud =clients.size();//recordá hacer esto para mayor eficiencia, así no calcula la longitud en cada iteración
        for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {
            System.out.println("Nº "+(i+1)+": "+clients.get(i).getClientName());
        }
    }   
}
class Client {

    private String clientName;
    private List<Double> transactions = new ArrayList<>();

    public Client(String clientName, double initialTransactions) {
        this.clientName = clientName;
        transactions.add(initialTransactions);//acá no hace falta el 'this' por que no hay confusión
        System.out.println("Cliente creado");
    }
    public String getClientName() {
        return clientName;
    }
    public void setClientName(String clientName) {
        this.clientName = clientName;
    }
    //este lo vas a usar cuando necesites acceder a una transacción en particular(con 'get(index)')
    public List<Double> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }
    public void addTransactions(double transaction) {
        this.transactions.add(transaction);
    }
    public void printTransactions(){
        System.out.println("Lista de Transacciones:");
        int longitud =transactions.size();//recordá hacer esto para mayor eficiencia, así no calcula la longitud en cada iteración
        for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {
            System.out.println("Nº "+(i+1)+": "+transactions.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. Hay algunos métodos que me vienen bien para practicar y mejorar el código. Podrías ver el OP? Agregué la clase que faltaba para que tengan un panorama más completo, ya que realicé las modificaciones sugeridas y sigo teniendo el problema. Saludos y nuevamente gracias.

Comment: @1990eam Hola, ya edité la respuesta. Si te sirvió no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Saludo!